# Tensorflow Issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I am trying to learn tensorflow, and I have modified the linear regression code that tensorflow provides on its website tutorial to do quadratic regression. However, instead of reducing the loss as it does in the linear model, the loss explodes and I have no idea why it's doing that.

Code, in python 2.7.12:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
A = tf.Variable([0], dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.Variable([0], dtype=tf.float32)
C = tf.Variable([0], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
model = A*(x**2)+B*x+C
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training data
x_train = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y_train = [0, 1, 4, 9]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(100):
  sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_A, curr_B, curr_C, curr_loss = sess.run([A, B, C, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
print("A: %s B: %s C: %s loss: %s"%(curr_A, curr_B, curr_C, curr_loss))
```

Here is the output:

```
A: [ -1.85999073e+10] B: [ -6.90063821e+09] C: [ -2.75790080e+09] loss: 4.55068e+22
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Edit: posted wrong code first

Comment: It could be that you are now overshooting in terms of the error for each data point. This can lead to the local minimum getting missed by ever increasing amounts on each iteration. It might be beneficial to take a close look at tf.square(model - y) to see if it is working as you'd expect. My ML knowledge is theoretical only - especially in terms of TensorFlow

Comment: @Steve Mostly correct. You did help me focus there. I checked optimizer, and the value I passed in was way too large. Using 0.001 allowed the function to converge.

Answer (score 0):

This learning rate:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
```

Is too large.

with:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
```

output is:

```
A: [ 0.99987358] B: [ 0.00042567] C: [-0.00021291] loss: 7.5869e-08
```